# Test lambda locally with curl

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

Normally, for testing lambda locally, I use

```
sam local invoke WebhookFunction -e test.json
```

in `test.json`

```
{"body":"test"}
```

This valiable is passed to `event`.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
```

Now I want to do equivalent thing by `curl`

I tried this.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"body":"test"}'
```

however I think `{"body":"test"}` is not correctly passed to `event`.

I guess I need to set something more.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

This won't work, unless you have a lambda RIE (Runtime Interface Emulator) running as a proxy for the Lambda Runtime API locally.

Depending on the language you've written your lambda in, you need to build a docker image and run it locally.

Finally, you can do this:

```
$ curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{}'
```

This command invokes the Lambda function running in the container image and returns a response.

---

You can use one of the AWS base images for Lambda to build the container image for your function code.

Choose your lambda language and follow the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-images.html).

Finally, [test your lambda container locally with RIE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-test.html).

There's a really nice blog post that walks you through the entire process [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/).